# GmailApp to .showModalDialog script in sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-sheets-macros

I want to show the GmailApp 'create email' UI on a .showModalDialog method in Google Sheets.

So far, I have been able to create a mail merge macro that works perfectly fine with script editor & various HTML files. However, my next task is to allow the user to draft an email in Google Sheets within a .showModalDialog

Here is a screenshot from the popular MailMeteor, as to show you what I would like to emulate.

[image: Here is a screenshot from the popular MailMeteor, as to show you what I would like to emulate.]

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

**Show Modal Dialog**

```
function showModalDialog() {
  var html="";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'Modal Dialog');
}
```

[UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)